# How to customize version filename in Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a strange issue. I am trying to use master branch of carrierwave with Rails 3.2.xx project. I need to customize filenames of the versions. But when I add `full_filename` method in the version block, my original file also gets reduced to the dimensions specified for version.

When I remove `full_filename` method, it all works as expected, but thumb filename has `thumb_` prefix which I don't want.

Is there a new way to customize version filenames. I have been using this way successfully in 0.10.0 and before.

Below is my uploader. This is a generated uploader with `store_dir` overrides.

```
class TestUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]

    def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}/#{version_name}"
    end

    def full_filename(for_file = model.logo.file)
      super(for_file).sub(version_name.to_s + '_', '')
    end
  end

end
```

Any ideas? All I need to do is to remove `version_name` part from its filename, since I am saving the versions in separate folders. I searched through Wiki and internet, but couldn't find a new way of doing this.

Comment: Seeing its definition, please once just try `super(for_file)` and nothing else. It should return you the filename.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it does return filename, but it starts with `thumb_`.

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Customize-your-version-file-names

Comment: @D.Pedoneze, this is what I got the idea, but it's not working on the master branch. It works in previous versions. The wiki might need updating.

Answer (score 0):

Add an initializer *carrierwave.rb* and mokeypatch the gem with:

```
module CarrierWave
  module Uploader
    module Versions
      private
        # Use original file name instead of prepending version name
        # Can't overload in app's uploader class because `super` already has
        # the version name
        def full_filename(for_file)
          directory = version_name.to_s
          # if you want the original version in a sub-directory also
          # directory = (version_name || 'original').to_s
          File.join(directory, super(for_file))
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, leave off the `store_dir` and `full_filename` methods from the versions.